# Why are there lots of warnings in the Firefox DevTools and Firebug console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, firebug

I have a lot of warnings in the Firefox and the Firebug console. I don't know what to do with them. Are they my fault? Also, how can I make debugging clear and useful in Firefox?

Here are the examples:

[image: Warnings in Firefox DevTools console]

[image: Warnings in Firebug console]

> [11:06:16.845] function cf does not always return a value @
>   http://example.hu/jquery.js:16 [11:06:16.853] function ce
>   does not always return a value @
>   http://example.hu/jquery.js:16 [11:06:16.861] function bZ
>   does not always return a value @
>   http://example.hu/jquery.js:16 [11:06:16.870] test for
>   equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? @
>   http://example.hu/jquery.js:16 [11:06:16.880] function M
>   does not always return a value @
>   http://example.hu/jquery.js:16 [11:06:16.889] anonymous
>   function does not always return a value @
>   http://example.hu/jquery.js:16 [11:06:16.921] test for
>   equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? @
>   http://example.hu/jquery.js:16 [11:06:16.934] anonymous
>   function does not always return a value @
>   http://example.hu/jquery.js:16 [11:06:16.957] test for
>   equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? @
>   http://example.hu/jquery.js:16 [11:06:16.972] anonymous
>   function does not always return a value @
>   http://example.hu/jquery.js:17 [11:06:16.998] test for
>   equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? @
>   http://example.hu/jquery.js:17 [11:06:17.012] anonymous
>   function does not always return a value @
>   http://example.hu/jquery.js:17 [11:06:17.035] test for
>   equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? @
>   http://example.hu/jquery.js:17 [11:06:17.051] anonymous
>   function does not always return a value @
>   http://example.hu/jquery.js:17 [11:06:17.073] test for
>   equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? @
>   http://example.hu/jquery.js:17 [11:06:17.086] anonymous
>   function does not always return a value @
>   http://example.hu/jquery.js:17 [11:06:17.126] test for
>   equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? @
>   http://example.hu/jquery.js:18 [11:06:17.153] anonymous
>   function does not always return a value @
>   http://example.hu/jquery.js:18 [11:06:17.175] reference to
>   undefined property f.valHooks[this] @
>   http://example.hu/jquery.js:16 [11:06:17.208] reference to
>   undefined property a[f.expando] @
>   http://example.hu/jquery.js:16 [11:06:17.376] reference to
>   undefined property a[f.expando] @
>   http://example.hu/jquery.js:16 [11:06:17.480] reference to
>   undefined property a[f.expando] @
>   http://example.hu/jquery.js:16 [11:06:17.613] reference to
>   undefined property f.event.triggered @
>   http://example.hu/jquery.js:16

```
reference to undefined property fbs.breakOnDebugCall
[Break On This Error] var hookReturn = d...e, errorInfo, fbs.breakOnDebugCall);
firebu...vice.js (line 1857)
<System>
reference to undefined property a[f.expando]
[Break On This Error] (function(a,b){function cv(a){return f...ndexOf(".")>=0&&(i=h.split("."),h=i.
jquery.js (line 16)
reference to undefined property fbs.breakOnDebugCall
[Break On This Error] return this.breakOnErrors || fbs.breakOnDebugCall;
firebu...vice.js (line 3523)
<System>
reference to undefined property fbs.breakOnDebugCall
[Break On This Error] var hookReturn = d...e, errorInfo, fbs.breakOnDebugCall);
firebu...vice.js (line 1857)
<System>
reference to undefined property a[f.expando]
[Break On This Error] (function(a,b){function cv(a){return f...ndexOf(".")>=0&&(i=h.split("."),h=i.
jquery.js (line 16)
reference to undefined property fbs.breakOnDebugCall
[Break On This Error] return this.breakOnErrors || fbs.breakOnDebugCall;
firebu...vice.js (line 3523)
<System>
reference to undefined property fbs.breakOnDebugCall
[Break On This Error] var hookReturn = d...e, errorInfo, fbs.breakOnDebugCall);
firebu...vice.js (line 1857)
<System>
reference to undefined property a[f.expando]
[Break On This Error] (function(a,b){function cv(a){return f...ndexOf(".")>=0&&(i=h.split("."),h=i.
jquery.js (line 16)
reference to undefined property fbs.breakOnDebugCall
[Break On This Error] return this.breakOnErrors || fbs.breakOnDebugCall;
firebu...vice.js (line 3523)
<System>
reference to undefined property fbs.breakOnDebugCall
[Break On This Error] var hookReturn = d...e, errorInfo, fbs.breakOnDebugCall);
firebu...vice.js (line 1857)
<System>
reference to undefined property a[f.expando]
[Break On This Error] (function(a,b){function cv(a){return f...ndexOf(".")>=0&&(i=h.split("."),h=i.
```

Comment: When you have a closer look, you'll see that these warnings are coming from jQuery. So, definitely not your fault :-).

Comment: Yes that's a lot of errors. Was there really a need to post it all 4 times though? "Are they my fault?" - if it's your code, then yes they are. To be honest the errors are all pretty self explanatory. If you double click them in Firebug it'll show you the line causing the error. Finally, without posting your code how do you expect us to help you?

Comment: http://teleprintfejl.inter.hu/fotokidolgozas/elohivas-beallitasok.php
every scripts can be found in the source. jquery version is:v1.6.2

Comment: The warnings are normal, and nothing to worry about. Most of them are from anonymous functions, breaks, and other stuff that throws warnings that are just that, warnings. If you click the error button in your Firebug console that should however be clear, as errors are bad. Warnings, not so much, and yes, I get the same results in Firebug with the latest jQuery, and lots of other scripts as well! It seems anything made by Facebook is especially bad when it comes to warnings, but again, it does'nt really matter!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To avoid them to be logged into the Console, you can uncheck [*Strict Warnings*](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_Panel#Options_Menu).

Answer (score 1):

Set *javascript.options.strict* to *false* under Firefox *about:config*.